# Como obtener la url de los video de Fembed

Tags: javascript, html, api, aplicación-web, html-video

Estoy intentando obtener el link directo a los videos de fembed:
aqui les dejo un link de prueba:
https://www.fembed.com/v/g5q88c-8r5nrw-7

Lo que necesito conseguir es un link parecido a este

https://fvs.io/redirector?token=T0JENEhYL3kzNDN2TmRQOFlTaDcyMnZITmpCSmdMYTRCN2IrL2ZDNFQrN2xIVllxR2xlOUZFOHpnRXk1SzZyWFJTKzcvWmxvdE1ob2l1OVpsQkNFQ0xyOWdnMS8rSzNkYTcxalNUbk9Ga05rYmh0Y09IZzgxWWltTDZ1Z1VvQlNySm0xUmdCQTdqaERSY3o4OGNUV2l5bkJHZGdGUVhvZzpvT3ZRbFA4VXRkV3ZQNU1SVEFMRmtnPT0SLyK

para poder usarlo en una aplicacion de movil.

He probado con este link,

```
https://fapi.deta.dev/g5q88c-8r5nrw-7
```

pero este me genera los urls, pero me dan Error 404 o 403.

**EDIT**

[Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510633/todo-bien-en-local-pero-cuando-lo-publico-no-funciona) esta el problema que estoy teniendo ahora

Comment: Pues el enlace de ejemplo redirige a otra URL. Yo consultaría con la gente de fembed para ver cómo se puede hacer. Desde afuera sólo se ve la documentación de la [API](https://www.fembed.com/api#video-information)

Comment: Ya les consulte pero dicen que no es posible, pero ya hay otros servicios que si lo han logrado

Comment: Ya ahí estás entrando en terreno de respetar o no los términos de uso y en SO la idea es no dar ideas que se salten ese tipo de cosas...

Comment: @Alfabravo no redirige a otra url de saque, solo cuando intentas inspeccionar el codigo. Vamos, que esta protegida para que no consigan lo que pretende el OP.

Comment: ya logre conseguir los enlaces (usando su API), pero me sucede algo muy extraño y es que cuando los enlaces los genero desde local funcionan pero si lo hago publicado en mi dominio, esté me genera enlaces que no son validos @masterguru

Answer (score 0):

Si, te fijas cuando lo hace en un Server Local el toma la IP en formato Ipv4 porque toma el IP de tu server LOCAL, mientras que si lo haces en un SERVER remoto este usa Ipv6 del Server Remoto.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Y como podría hacer la solicitud y forzar que utilice la IPV4 en php?